# Eclipse Run Configuration Multiple Resource Selection

Tags: java, eclipse

I have run into a situation where I would like to select multiple resources in Eclipse to send their paths as arguments for `main( String[] args )`, but sadly the variable `selected_resource_loc` only sends the path of the first resource.
 Is the any way I can select several resources in the workspace and have each of their paths be sent to `String[] args`?
 For example I have 2 files in my project and I would like to select them and run a configuration of a Java application where the paths of these files would be `args[0]` and `args[1]`

Comment: You should make your question clearly.

Comment: The description of the variable `selected_resource_loc` says : `Returns the absolute file system path of the selected resource.` So it will be one. Where are your selected resources ? Are they in a project ?

Comment: @svasa Yes, they are in a project

Comment: Because the project will be in a package explorer, you should be able to use : `IWorkbenchWindow window =
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
ISelection selection = window.getSelectionService().getSelection("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer");`

Comment: @svasa Is there any way of doing it without importing org.eclipse?

Comment: what do you mean without importing `org.eclipse`, aren't you using it already when you try to access `selected_resource_loc` ?

Comment: @svasa I am using ${selected_resource_loc} as a Program argument in the run configuration, taken from the default variables. I haven't used run configurations before, so I am probably not understanding something, but if I try to write that chunk of code it says it does not have org.eclipse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115423/discussion-between-svasa-and-semikel).

Comment: I perfectly understand his question, having the same problem. I execute a Java program by running its configuration (menu Run > Run Configurations...) In the "Java Application" section, I can find my program configuration, then in its "Arguments" tab (on the right), I put "${selected_resource_loc}" in the "Program arguments:" field.
And then, I select files in the Java project, e.g. files under "src/main/resources", and click the green Run icon.

Comment: For you e.g. @svasa to understand, let's say you have this:
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Arrays.stream(args).forEach(path -> {
       File file = new File(args[0]);
       System.out.println("Reading " + file.getPath());
      });
    }
The loop only runs for the 1st file selected.